# How to notice MySQL errors using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is what the PHP manual said:

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing all of the
>   remaining rows in the result set. The array represents each row as
>   either an array of column values or an object with properties
>   corresponding to each column name. An empty array is returned if there
>   are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.
>   http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php

The thing is I get the FALSE returned always, if there is no other thing to fetch. (For example if I do an SQL UPDATE or INSERT)..
Even if there was no problem and everything worked just fine..
What can I do about that? I want to notice if there went something wrong.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking explicitly for false?  `===`

```
If ($result === false) {
}
```

The above is not the same as `if (! $result) {...` or `if ($result == false) {...`  Those would equate to true if the value was zero or an empty array too.

You also might want to look at the [ERRMODE setting for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).  It can be set to throw exceptions for certain errors.  You can then use try / catch blocks.

`$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Haha.. Im so stupid .. thank you.
I did not the === only == :P

I will mark your answer in 6 mins ^^